# Alternate of Perfmon to check load of apache server in rhel with load from Jmeter

Tags: apache, performance, server, load-testing, rhel

Due to the firewall, i am unable to use Perfmon to check a load of apache server in RHEL with the load from Jmeter. So I Need some other tool which can be used to measure CPU and memory utilization of the RHEL 7 apache server. If there is any tool which can be used to check performance of load kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a free or a paid solution? You can take a look at OctoPerf, we support **monitoring** dozen of backend technologies combined with **JMeter** load testing. Our [on-premise monitoring](https://octoperf.com/monitoring/) agent supports out-of-the-box monitoring for Apache Httpd Server, Linux Operating system and more.

If you look for free solutions, then you can take a look at [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/).